# best practice: what directory should the theme be located for a site install profile

Tags: theming, installation-profiles

I am building a site install profile. Trying to wrap my head around the file structure.
I am creating a Drupal 7 install profile with a sub theme off of omega.

Is it better practice to put the theme in the

```
profile/themes
```

or

```
sites/all/themes
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, the theme would go in:

```
/profiles/YOURPROFILE/themes/YOURSUBTHEME
```

Also include the base theme at the same location:

```
/profiles/YOURPROFILE/themes/omega
```